# Combine checkout payment method and order review

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, payment-methods

Extending the default Magento One Page Checkout:

is there a way to combine in one single step Payment Method (Step 4) and Order Review (Step 5) ?

If not possible is there a way to revert their order ?

Because usually a customer first has to check if the order then can send the payment.

Using paypal as unique payment method this doesn't happen.

After the point 4 the user is automatically redirect to the paypal page.

I know that other users marked this question as duplicate but unfortunately they didn't read well the solution they gave me:
[OneStepSolution Provided](http://www.divisionlab.com/solvingmagento/onestep-checkout-a-magento-tutorial-part-1-steps-1-4-of-12/)

Says:

> In my extension I will not restrict myself to any specific scenario; instead, I will attempt to build a OneStep checkout as a replacement to the fully fledged Magento OnePage checkout.

Comment: I'm sorry my question is not a duplicate. Even because the question you linked doesn't have a valid solution.

Comment: Actually the link in the answer details how to turn multiple steps into a onestepcheckout. With that info you can build a module to to combine the payment and review steps

Comment: Well, and entire tutorial that edits all the checkout system is not a specific solution to my problem. I would like to maintain the one page checkout layout.

Comment: We are not here to provide you with ready to go solutions. We're not getting paid to support people on this forum and do expect people to put in some effort to fix the issues they have. If you want a plug and play solution hire a freelancer

Comment: Sander, I didn't ask you to do it for me. I'm asking to the community to help me. You answered with something that I don't need. I asked for a way to use the Magento Core One Page Checkout and combine orrRevert the order of Payment Method and Order Review. Can I have an answer to this problem? If you're not able to do it please let other users help me.